# Persist Page-state when navigating between Pages

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to let the user use a phone's back button in order to return to a previous screen. In order to do that I thought of using `frame.Navigate()`. However, this means that I need to supply a `Type` instead of a specific `Page`. But I want the user to return to the original Page as it was left. So how do I achieve that?

If I'm using the wrong method for this, please let me know. I want to use whatever is the correct method for doing this.

Comment: Have you tried to define `NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;` in *Page's* constructor?

Comment: @Romasz Thanks. That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [NavigationCacheMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br227506) of your *Page* to 'Required'. Then page state should be cached.

Note also that OS can free resources in some cases, so be also prepared for fresh page.

Answer (score 1):

To return to previous screen, use [Frame.GoBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242692). Your old page is intact in navigation stack.

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately the old page is not as it was left.